# is it possible to find a value exist in object array in php (wordpress) without using loop

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

i joined wp_post and wp_post_meta table and resulted in this object array. Can i find a value of field1 exists in the array without using any loops. 
field1==1150 exists
field1==2150 doesnt exists

```
array (size=4)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[1306]
      public 'ID' => string '415' (length=3)
      public 'post_title' => string 'hello' (length=22)
      public 'field1' => string '' (length=0)
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[1307]
      public 'ID' => string '473' (length=3)
      public 'post_title' => string 'hai' (length=6)
      public 'field1' => string '1150' (length=0)
  2 => 
    object(stdClass)[1308]
      public 'ID' => string '1189' (length=4)
      public 'post_title' => string 'news test' (length=9)
      public 'field1' => string '1187' (length=4)
  3 => 
    object(stdClass)[1309]
      public 'ID' => string '1208' (length=4)
      public 'post_title' => string 'news test r' (length=11)
      public 'field1' => string '1189' (length=4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since PHP 7 [array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) works on objects too.

```
$field1 = array_column($objarr, "field1");
// Now you have a flat array you can use in_array or array_search on.
$key = array_search(1150, $field1);
if($key !== false){
    echo "found at key " . $key;
}
```

Comment: any solution inphp 5

Comment: @roopesh not that I'm aware of. But in the background array_column loops the values, and I'm quite sure array_search does it too. If that assumption is correct then my code "without loops" loops the array twice, doing a normal loop will only loop the array once. It's only a matter of where you want to loop the values in PHP or in the back